# What is the importance of returning reference in operator overloading

Tags: c++

Can anybody explain why do you need to return a reference while overloading operators
e.g.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const std::string& str)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is to make "chaining" of the operator work, in examples like this:

```
std::cout << "hello," << " world";
```

If the first (leftmost) use of the `operator<<()` hadn't returned a reference, there would not be an object to call for the second use of the operator.

Comment: heh :) the "beat me to it" problem is so awful, esp on crowded communities like SO

Answer (score 4):

It's for operator chaining (if you return a pointer, you have to dereference it) and for not make a potentially huge and expensive copy of an object (in the case you return a value), if it is even possible to do so.

Comment: ... if you can even perform a copy of the object received. What should a copy of std::cout be?

Answer (score 3):

A general rule, stated by Scott Meyers in Effective C++, is that when in doubt, "do as the `ints` do". So for example, operator= should return a reference so code like this works:

```
MyClass A, B, C;
A = B = C = 0;
```